# LoadError on require

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, zsh

I have a simple ruby script that is using the `net-ping` gem which I have installed with `gem install net-ping` and have confirmation that it has installed:

```
Successfully installed net-ping-1.7.8
Parsing documentation for net-ping-1.7.8
Done installing documentation for net-ping after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

In my script:
    require 'net/ping'

```
def can_ping(host)
  @icmp = Net::Ping::ICMP.new(host)
  if @icmp.ping
    can_ping = true
  else
    can_ping = false
  end
end

can_ping(www.google.com)
```

In irb this all works fine, however when trying to run my script, it doesn't.  Instead I get this error now:

```
/Users/golem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/ping (LoadError)
from /Users/golem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from checkin.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

This used to work fine on an older version of my script, however, I've since installed `Oh-My-Zsh` on my Mac, which I suspect is the issue.

So, I made sure my environment variables reference RVM (`printenv`):

```
rvm_prefix=/Users/golem
rvm_path=/Users/golem/.rvm
rvm_bin_path=/Users/golem/.rvm/bin
```

Is there something else that I'm missing that could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, net ping requires root privileges to run. So, if you are using sudo, the gem needs to be installed again. so, do `sudo su` first,  run the `gem install net-ping:1.7.8` again and try running your script.

That should work.